# Input do tipo imagem não envia o formulario?

Tags: php, input

Estou tendo um problema pra dar submit com o input type image, ele simplesmente não é reconhecido como submit e não envia os dados para serem processados pelo POST.

Abaixo é as formas que não deu certo.

Tentando enviar com o id do input:

```
<input type="image" name="botao" id="buttonSubmit" onClick="document.getElementById('buttonSubmit').submit();" src="css/img/buttonImg.png" style="width:223px;height:41px"/>
```

Pegando o formulário e tentando dar submit

```
<input type="image" name="botao" id="buttonSubmit" onClick="document.getElementById('formulario').submit();" src="css/img/buttonImg.png" style="width:223px;height:41px"/>
```

Normal sem js:

```
<input  type="image" name="botao" id="buttonSubmit" src="css/img/buttonImg.png" style="width:223px;height:41px" />
```

Já tentei de todas as formas que vi na net mas nenhuma deu certo, então estou recorrendo a vocês!

Como deu certo:

```
<input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="buttonSubmit" name="botao"/>
```

Da forma acima funciona perfeitamente... mas eu quero usar uma imagem como submit... e não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum!

Meu código completo:

```
<?php
require ("includes/connection.php");
?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <title> KNAUTILUZ </title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <link href="css/main-index.css" rel="stylesheet">
          <img src="css/img/backmenu.png" alt="" title="" id="field0"/>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="js/pegarValor.js"></script>
          <img src="css/img/gameLogo.png" alt="" title="" id="gameLogo"/>
          <div id="text" >Knautiluz é um jogo online de navegador (browser).<br>Trazendo uma proposta inovadora de um RPG de mesa.<br> Cada jogador pode ser o que desejar, tudo depende de <br> sua imaginação.</div>
          <div id="upperMenu"></div>
          <form name="formulario" id="formulario" action="" method="post">
             <label id="nomediv">Nome</label>
             <input type="text" required placeholder="SEU NOME" name="name" id="name" pattern="[A-z]{3,}" maxlength="12">
             <br>
             <label id="sobrenomediv">Sobrenome</label>
             <input type="text" required placeholder="SOBRENOME" name="surname" id="surname" pattern="[A-z]{3,}" maxlength="12">
             <br>
             <label id="nascimentodiv">Nascimento</label>
             <input type="date" required  name="birthday" id="birthday" min="1915-01-01" max="2006-01-01"> 
             <br>
             <label id="sexdiv">Sexo</label>
             <select name="sex" id="sex">
                <option value="Male">MASCULINO</option>
                <option value="Female">FEMININO</option>
             </select>
             <br>
             <label id="userdiv">Usuário</label>
             <input type="text" required placeholder="USUARIO" name="username" id="username" pattern="[A-z]{3,}" maxlength="15">
             <br>
             <label id="emaildiv">E-mail</label>
             <input type="email" required placeholder="E-MAIL@PROVEDOR.COM" name="email" id="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$">
             <br>
             <label id="senhadiv">Senha</label>
             <input type="password" required placeholder="SENHA" name="password" id="password" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" title="Precisa ter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula uma letra minúscula, um numero e 6 ou mais caracteres">
             <input type="hidden" name="status" id="status" value="1">
             <br>
             <label id="csenhadiv">Confirme a senha</label>
             <input id="repassword" name="repassword" type="password" required  placeholder="CONFIRME A SENHA" title="Coloque a senha igual a anterior para confirma-la" pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,}" title="Precisa ter pelo menos uma letra maiúscula uma letra minúscula, um numero e 6 ou mais caracteres" oninput="validaSenha(this)" />
             <br>
             <br>
             <br>
             <input type="image" name="botao" id="buttonSubmit" onClick="this.form.submit();" src="css/img/buttonImg.png" style="width:223px;height:41px"/>
             <br>
             <br>
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
    <?php
if (isset($_POST["botao"]))
{
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["name"]);
    $surname = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["surname"]);
    $birthday = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["birthday"]);
    $sex = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["sex"]);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["username"]);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["email"]);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["password"]);
    $repassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST["repassword"]);

    if ($name == "" || $surname == "" || $birthday == "" || $sex == "" || $username == "" || $email == "" || $password == "" || $repassword == "")
    {
        echo "<script> alert('Preencha todos os campos.'); </script>";
        return true;
    }
    if ($password != $repassword)
    {
        echo "<script> alert('As senhas devem ser iguais!'); </script>";
        return true;
    }
    // FAZ A BUSCA NO BDD PRA VER SE O EMAIL JA EXISTE
    $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE email='$email'");
    if (select)
    {
        $row = $select->num_rows;
        if ($row > 0)
        {
            echo "<script> alert('Já existe um usuário com este e-mail!'); </script>";
        }
        else
        {
            // FAZ A BUSCA NO BDD PRA VER SE O USUARIO JA EXISTE
            $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE username='$username'");
            if (select)
            {
                $row = $select->num_rows;
                if ($row > 0)
                {
                    echo "<script> alert('O Usuário já existe.'); </script>";
                }
                else
                {
                    // CASO TUDO ESTIVER OK ELE INSERE AS INFORMAÇÕES NO BDD
                    $insert = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `data`(`name`, `surname`, `birthday`, `sex`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `status`) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$birthday', '$sex', '$username', '$email', '" . md5($password) . "', '0')");
                    if ($insert)
                    {
                        echo "<script> alert('Usuario registrado com sucesso!'); location.href='login.php' </script>";
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                echo $mysqli->error;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todos os casos possuem um problema diferente.

Quando você usa o `input` do tipo `image` ele gera dois valores, de X e de Y.

**Exemplo:**

```
<form method='post'>
    <input type='image' src='/caminho/para/imagem' name='biscoito'>
</form>
```

Isso irá enviar um `POST` com `biscoito.x` e `biscoito.y`.

Portanto, você está declarando uma condição inválida, do tipo:

```
if(isset($_POST["biscoito"])) { }
```

O `biscoito` nunca irá existir, mas em  seu lugar existirá `biscoito.x` e o `biscoito.y`, simples assim.

Nesse caso usar a condição:

```
if(isset($_POST["biscoito.x"], $_POST["biscoito.y"])) { }
// OU 
if(isset($_POST)){ }
```

Iria resolver o problema.

**Nota:**

> Alterei o `name` de `botao` para `biscoito` para que não se confunda o
>   botão `input` com o botão `name`, acho que assim consegue entender mais fácil o problema!

**Mas e com o JavaScript?**

Então, com o uso do `.submit()` (ou similar) você ignora a existência do `name` do próprio botão, portanto você não irá enviar o `name` que for escolhido no `input!

Comment: Inkeliz, não entendi muito bem... esses valores, x e y teriam algum nome? Porque dessa forma também não funcionou... o que fiz foi criar um input hidden e colocar no name o valor que eu queria pegar através do php... ai funcionou belezinha...

Comment: Esse .x e .y é inserido quando é um botao do tipo image, de maneira automática. Se o nome do input for "OK" terá OK.x e OK.y

Answer (score 1):

Coloque um value no no input por isso não esta dando certo testei aqui e funcionou `<input type="image" value="cadastrar">`